Rabbitmq with email
I've been asked to setup rabbitMq with email with docker compose on a linux VM.  It works as far as I can tell from the management console without any error when I start it up, or creating exchanges & ques.
Here is current set up:
To add the email plugin:
ARG RABBITMQ_VERSION=3.12.11

FROM elixir:1.14.5 as builder
ARG RABBITMQ_VERSION

ENV TZ=Europe/London
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt update && apt install -y rsync
RUN cd $HOME; git clone --depth 1 --branch v${RABBITMQ_VERSION}  https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server.git
RUN cd $HOME/rabbitmq-server && make FULL=1
RUN cd $HOME/rabbitmq-server/deps && git clone --depth 1 --branch v1.1.1 https://github.com/gotthardp/rabbitmq-email.git
RUN cd $HOME/rabbitmq-server/deps/rabbitmq-email && make RABBITMQ_VERSION=v${RABBITMQ_VERSION} dist

FROM docker.io/bitnami/rabbitmq:${RABBITMQ_VERSION}

COPY --from=builder /root/rabbitmq-server/deps/rabbitmq-email/plugins/eiconv-1.0.0 /opt/bitnami/rabbitmq/plugins/eiconv-1.0.0
COPY --from=builder /root/rabbitmq-server/deps/rabbitmq-email/plugins/gen_smtp-1.2.0 /opt/bitnami/rabbitmq/plugins/gen_smtp-1.2.0
COPY --from=builder /root/rabbitmq-server/deps/rabbitmq-email/plugins/rabbitmq_email-1.1.1 /opt/bitnami/rabbitmq/plugins/rabbitmq_email-1.1.1


My compose file:
services:
  rabbitmq-ssl:
    image: rabbit-email:0.1
    hostname: 'rabbitmq-server'
    user: root
    container_name: 'rabbitmq-with-mail'
    restart: always
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_MANAGEMENT_ALLOW_WEB_ACCESS=true
      - RABBITMQ_PLUGINS=rabbitmq_management,rabbitmq_email,rabbitmq_amqp1_0,rabbitmq_shovel,rabbitmq_shovel_management,gen_smtp
      - RABBITMQ_EMAIL_SMTP_SERVER=smtp.*******.com
        #- RABBITMQ_NODE_NAME=rabbitmq
      - RABBITMQ_NODE_NAME=rabbitmq
      - RABBITMQ_EMAIL_SMTP_PORT=25
      - RABBITMQ_EMAIL_SMTP_FROM=noreply@*******.com
      - RABBITMQ_EMAIL_SMTP_TO=alerts@*******.com
      - RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE=*********
      - RABBITMQ_MANAGEMENT_SSL_CACERTFILE=/etc/ssl/rmq-cacert.pem
      - RABBITMQ_MANAGEMENT_SSL_CERTFILE=/etc/ssl/rmq-cert.pem
      - RABBITMQ_MANAGEMENT_SSL_KEYFILE=/etc/ssl/rmq-key.pem       
      - RABBITMQ_SSL_CACERTFILE=/etc/ssl/cacert.pem
      - RABBITMQ_SSL_CERTFILE=/etc/ssl/cert.pem
      - RABBITMQ_SSL_KEYFILE=/etc/ssl/key.pem
      - RABBITMQ_NODE_SSL_PORT_NUMBER=5671
      - RABBITMQ_SSL_VERIFY=verify_peer
      - RABBITMQ_SSL_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT=t/etc/ssl/rmq-cacert.pem
      - RABBITMQ_MANAGEMENT_SSL_DEPTH=3
      - RABBITMQ_SSL_DEPTH=3
    ports:
      - "5671:5671"  
      - "15672:15672"
      - "15692:15692"
    volumes:
      - 'rabbitmq_data:/bitnami/rabbitmq/mnesia'
      - ./conf/rabbitmq.conf:/opt/bitnami/rabbitmq/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
      - ./conf/rabbitmq_email:/opt/bitnami/rabbitmq/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq_email
      - ./certs/intermediate.crt:/etc/ssl/cacert.pem:ro
      - ./certs/total.crt:/etc/ssl/cert.pem:ro
      - ./certs/rabbitmq.pem:/etc/ssl/key.pem:ro
volumes:
  rabbitmq_data:
    driver: local

problem
Within the container I try to find status:
root@rabbitmq-server:/# rabbitmqctl status
Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbitmq@rabbitmq-server'. Please see diagnostics information and suggestions below.

Most common reasons for this are:

 * Target node is unreachable (e.g. due to hostname resolution, TCP connection or firewall issues)
 * CLI tool fails to authenticate with the server (e.g. due to CLI tool's Erlang cookie not matching that of the server)
 * Target node is not running

In addition to the diagnostics info below:

 * See the CLI, clustering and networking guides on https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more
 * Consult server logs on node rabbitmq@rabbitmq-server
 * If target node is configured to use long node names, don't forget to use --longnames with CLI tools

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: ['rabbitmq@rabbitmq-server']

rabbitmq@rabbitmq-server:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on rabbitmq-server
  * epmd reports node 'rabbitmq' uses port 25672 for inter-node and CLI tool traffic
  * TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed
  * suggestion: check if the Erlang cookie is identical for all server nodes and CLI tools
  * suggestion: check if all server nodes and CLI tools use consistent hostnames when addressing each other
  * suggestion: check if inter-node connections may be configured to use TLS. If so, all nodes and CLI tools must do that
   * suggestion: see the CLI, clustering and networking guides on https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more


Current node details:
 * node name: 'rabbitmq@rabbitmq-server'
 * effective user's home directory: /opt/bitnami/rabbitmq/.rabbitmq
 * Erlang cookie hash: E************==

I've checked the erlang cookie and node name (it is on one node) which have been hardcoded.
